# How do I draw a circle in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

```
let block = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(cellWidth-25, cellHeight/2-8, 16, 16))
block.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex: 0xff3b30)
block.layer.cornerRadius = 9
block.clipsToBounds = true
```

This is what I have right now, but it's obviously not the right way to do it.

What's the simplest way to do it?

Comment: You have a number of ways you can do this, SpriteKit, Core Graphics, etc. You should probably nail it down a little more for us.

Comment: Cannot see the slightest reason, at all, anyone would vote to close this question?

Comment: @Joe I'm pretty sure you can earn points as an administrator for certain activities, including closing questions.  That probably explains why five people are cited as closing the question when (for four of them) it was already closed.

Comment: Questions about improving working code are better asked on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 222, accepted):

### Alert. This old answer is absolutely incorrect.

> ***WARNING!* This is an incorrect solution. layers are added infinitely in the `drawRect` method (every time the view is drawn). You should NEVER add layers in the `drawRect` method. Use `layoutSubview` instead.**

You can draw a circle with this (*Swift 3.0+*):

```swift
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100), radius: CGFloat(20), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)
    
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
    
// Change the fill color
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
// You can change the stroke color
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
// You can change the line width
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
    
view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

With the code you have posted you are cropping the corners of the `UIView`, not adding a circle to the view.

---

Here's a full example of using that method:

```swift
/// A special UIView displayed as a ring of color
class Ring: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        drawRingFittingInsideView()
    }
    
    internal func drawRingFittingInsideView() -> () {
        let halfSize:CGFloat = min( bounds.size.width/2, bounds.size.height/2)
        let desiredLineWidth:CGFloat = 1 // your desired value
            
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(
                arcCenter: CGPoint(x:halfSize,y:halfSize),
                radius: CGFloat( halfSize - (desiredLineWidth/2) ),
                startAngle: CGFloat(0),
                endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2),
                clockwise: true)
    
         let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
         shapeLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath
            
         shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
         shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
         shapeLayer.lineWidth = desiredLineWidth
    
         layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
     }
}
```

[image: A circle outlined in red and filled with yellow on a yellow background.]

---

Note, however there's an incredibly handy call:

## `let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)`

which does all the work of making the path. (Don't forget to inset it for the line thickness, which is also incredibly easy with `CGRectInset`.)

```swift
internal func drawRingFittingInsideView(rect: CGRect) {
    let desiredLineWidth:CGFloat = 4    // Your desired value
    let hw:CGFloat = desiredLineWidth/2
    
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectInset(rect,hw,hw))
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = desiredLineWidth
    layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

[image: An ellipses (oval-like) outlined in red and filled with yellow on a yellow background.]

---

In practice these days in Swift, you would certainly use `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable`. Using these you can actually **see and change the rendering, in Storyboard!**

As you can see, it actually adds new features to the Inspector on the Storyboard, which you can change on the Storyboard:

[image: Xcode Storyboard Attributes Inspector with custom fields.]

```
/// A dot with a border, which you can control completely in Storyboard
@IBDesignable class Dot: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var mainColor: UIColor = UIColor.blueColor() {
        didSet { 
             print("mainColor was set here")
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var ringColor: UIColor = UIColor.orangeColor() {
         didSet {
             print("bColor was set here") 
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var ringThickness: CGFloat = 4 {
        didSet { 
            print("ringThickness was set here")
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var isSelected: Bool = true
    
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let dotPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect:rect)
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = dotPath.CGPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = mainColor.CGColor
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        
        if (isSelected) { 
            drawRingFittingInsideView(rect)
        }
    }
    
    internal func drawRingFittingInsideView(rect: CGRect) {
        let hw:CGFloat = ringThickness/2
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectInset(rect,hw,hw) )
        
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = ringColor.CGColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = ringThickness
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

---

Finally, note that if you have a `UIView` (which is square, and which you set to say red in Storyboard) and you simply want to turn it in to a red circle, you can just do the following:

```
// Makes a UIView into a circular dot of color
class Dot: UIView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.size.width/2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know the perf difference between using cornerRadius and BezierPath? Just curious :)

Comment: `M_PI` is deprecated. It's now `Double.pi` (in Swift 3)

Comment: It is probably not good idea to add new CALayer in `func drawRect(rect: CGRect)` method, as this method is supposed to do custom drawing in its own layer, also this method would be called mulitple times.

Comment: Please, DO NOT ADD sublayers in drawRect method! 
First, drawRect is called multiple times during view lifecycle, literally every layout process. That means, you will end up having dozens of equal (or probably not) sublayers in your hierarchy, consuming memory and slowing your app down.
Second, drawRect isn't intended for modifying view hierarchy. If you really need to draw something special - you use it in conjunction with CoreGraphics context functions. Better way here - is just adding shape layer in init method.

Comment: Great answer. Using Swift type assumptions can shorten/simplify that bezier arc path definition: `arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 75, y: 75), radius: 140.0, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: true)` Because radius argument type is CGFloat, if you provide a Double (by adding .0, it can auto convert to CGFloat [whereas providing 140 defaulting to Int would not] ), 0 itself always autoconverts to whatever, so you don't need to typcastCGFloat, Double, Int, etc... Since endAngle specifies CGFloat arg, there's a CGFloat.pi variant, it's assumed that's what you mean when you just write '.pi * 2'...

Comment: This answer is unfortunately basically wrong.  When you add layers in iOS, you add the (almost alwys as a lazy var) and then resize them in `layoutSubviews`, which is the basic mechanism of anything in iOS

Answer (score 15):

Make a class UIView and assign it this code for a simple circle

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class DRAW: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        var path = UIBezierPath()
        path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
        UIColor.yellow.setStroke()
        UIColor.red.setFill()
        path.lineWidth = 5
        path.stroke()
        path.fill()


    }


}
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer to the date, others have major issue.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use a UIView to draw it, then you need to make the radius / of the height or width.

so just change:

```
block.layer.cornerRadius = 9
```

to:

```
block.layer.cornerRadius = block.frame.width / 2
```

You'll need to make the height and width the same however. If you'd like to use coregraphics, then you'll want to do something like this:

```
CGContextRef ctx= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGRect bounds = [self bounds];

CGPoint center;
center.x = bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width / 2.0;
center.y = bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height / 2.0;
CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx,5);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx,0.8,0.8,0.8,1.0);
CGContextAddArc(ctx,locationOfTouch.x,locationOfTouch.y,30,0.0,M_PI*2,YES);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
```

Comment: Very clever. Making a circle by using a square. Made it really easy for me.

Answer (score 7):

Here is my version using Swift 5 and Core Graphics.

I have created a class to draw two circles. The first circle is created using `addEllipse()`. It puts the ellipse into a square, thus creating a circle. I find it surprising that there is no function `addCircle()`. The second circle is created using `addArc()` of 2pi radians

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class DrawCircles: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            print("could not get graphics context")
            return
        }

        context.setLineWidth(2)

        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)

        context.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 50.0, height: 50.0))

        context.strokePath()

        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)

        context.beginPath() // this prevents a straight line being drawn from the current point to the arc

        context.addArc(center: CGPoint(x:100, y: 100), radius: 20, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2.0*CGFloat.pi, clockwise: false)

        context.strokePath()
    }
}
```

in your ViewController's `didViewLoad()` add the following:

```
let myView = DrawCircles(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 300, height: 300))

self.view.addSubview(myView)
```

When it runs it should look like this. I hope you like my solution!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4** version of accepted answer:

```
@IBDesignable
class CircledDotView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var mainColor: UIColor = .white {
        didSet { print("mainColor was set here") }
    }
    @IBInspectable var ringColor: UIColor = .black {
        didSet { print("bColor was set here") }
    }
    @IBInspectable var ringThickness: CGFloat = 4 {
        didSet { print("ringThickness was set here") }
    }

    @IBInspectable var isSelected: Bool = true

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let dotPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = dotPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = mainColor.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        if (isSelected) {
            drawRingFittingInsideView(rect: rect)
        }
    }

    internal func drawRingFittingInsideView(rect: CGRect) {
        let hw: CGFloat = ringThickness / 2
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect.insetBy(dx: hw, dy: hw))

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = ringColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = ringThickness
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are adding CALayer on every draw call, that can't be good as draw is called every time rect is invalidated. You need some if checks to check whether layer has been added already.

Answer (score 3):

Updating @Dario's code approach for Xcode 8.2.2, Swift 3.x.  Noting that in storyboard, set the Background color to "clear" to avoid a black background in the square UIView:

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class Dot:UIView
{
    @IBInspectable var mainColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear
        {
        didSet { print("mainColor was set here") }
    }
    @IBInspectable var ringColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear
        {
        didSet { print("bColor was set here") }
    }
    @IBInspectable var ringThickness: CGFloat = 4
        {
        didSet { print("ringThickness was set here") }
    }


    @IBInspectable var isSelected: Bool = true

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {

        let dotPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = dotPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = mainColor.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        if (isSelected) { drawRingFittingInsideView(rect: rect) }
    }

    internal func drawRingFittingInsideView(rect: CGRect)->()
    {
        let hw:CGFloat = ringThickness/2
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect.insetBy(dx: hw,dy: hw) )

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = ringColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = ringThickness
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

And if you want to control the start and end angles:

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class Dot:UIView
{
    @IBInspectable var mainColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear
        {
        didSet { print("mainColor was set here") }
    }
    @IBInspectable var ringColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear
        {
        didSet { print("bColor was set here") }
    }
    @IBInspectable var ringThickness: CGFloat = 4
        {
        didSet { print("ringThickness was set here") }
    }


    @IBInspectable var isSelected: Bool = true

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {

        let dotPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = dotPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = mainColor.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        if (isSelected) { drawRingFittingInsideView(rect: rect) }
    }

    internal func drawRingFittingInsideView(rect: CGRect)->()
    {
        let halfSize:CGFloat = min( bounds.size.width/2, bounds.size.height/2)
        let desiredLineWidth:CGFloat = ringThickness   // your desired value

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(
            arcCenter: CGPoint(x: halfSize, y: halfSize),
            radius: CGFloat( halfSize - (desiredLineWidth/2) ),
            startAngle: CGFloat(0),
            endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi),
            clockwise: true)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = ringColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = ringThickness
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Swift 3 translations, saved me a lot of time and testing!

Comment: WARNING! This is incorrect solution - layers are added infinitely in draw method (every time the view is drawn).

Comment: @AlexanderVolkov good catch. I’m away from my iOS dev station for a few weeks, do you have a fix or improvement?

Answer (score 3):

A much easier and resource friendly approach would be.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CircleDrawView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.red;

    @IBInspectable var borderSize: CGFloat = 4

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = borderSize
        layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height/2
    }

}
```

With `Border Color` and `Border Size` and the default `Background` property you can define the appearance of the circle.

[image]

Please note, to draw a circle the view's height and width have to be equal in size.

The code is working for `Swift >= 4` and `Xcode >= 9`.

Answer (score 1):

I find Core Graphics to be pretty simple for **Swift 3**:

```
if let cgcontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
    cgcontext.strokeEllipse(in: CGRect(x: center.x-diameter/2, y: center.y-diameter/2, width: diameter, height: diameter))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple function drawing a circle on the middle of your window frame, using a multiplicator percentage

```
/// CGFloat is a multiplicator from self.view.frame.width
func drawCircle(withMultiplicator coefficient: CGFloat) {

    let radius = self.view.frame.width / 2 * coefficient

    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: self.view.center, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

    //change the fill color
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0

    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### 2022, General example of how to actually draw using `draw` in a `UIView`.

It's not so easy to properly use `UIView#draw`.

- General beginner tips, you can only `draw` inside a UIView, it is meaningless otherwise. Further, you can only use the draw commands (`.fillEllipse` etc) inside the `draw` call of a UIView.
- You almost certainly want to set the **intrinsic content size** properly. It's important to fully understand how to use this on consumers views, in the two possible situations (a) you are using constraints (b) you are positioning the view by hand in `layoutSubviews` inside another view.
- A huge gotchya is that **you cannot** `draw` **outside the frame**, no matter what. In contrast if you just use lazy vars with a layer to draw a shape (whether dot, circle, etc) it's **no problem** if you go outside the nominal frame (indeed you often just make the frame size zero so that everything centers easily in your consumer code). But once you start using `draw` you MUST be inside the frame. This is often confusing as in some cases you "don't know how big your drawing is going to be" until you draw it.
- A huge gotchya is, when you are drawing either circles or edges, beginner programmers **accidentally cut off half the thickness** of that line, due to the fact that `draw` absolutely can't draw outside the frame. You have to inset the circle or rectangle, by, half the width of the line thickness.

Some code with correct 2022 syntax:

```
import UIKit
class ExampleDot: UIIView {
    
    // setup ..
    // clipsToBounds = false BUT SEE NOTES
    // backgroundColor = .clear
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        // example of a dot

        ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
        ctx.fillEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        
        // example of a round circle BUT SEE NOTES
        ctx.setStrokeColor(UIColor.systemYellow.cgColor)
        ctx.setLineWidth(2)
        ctx.strokeEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 1, y: 1, width: 40 - 4, height: 40 - 4))

        // example of a smaller inner dot
        ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
        ctx.fillEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20))

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in view did load

```
//Circle Points

var CircleLayer   = CAShapeLayer() 

let center = CGPoint (x: myCircleView.frame.size.width / 2, y: myCircleView.frame.size.height / 2)
let circleRadius = myCircleView.frame.size.width / 2
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)
CircleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
CircleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
CircleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
CircleLayer.lineWidth = 8
CircleLayer.strokeStart = 0
CircleLayer.strokeEnd  = 1
Self.View.layer.addSublayer(CircleLayer)
```