# Xamarin iOS: Why there is a line from the center to arc of the circle

Tags: ios, xamarin, drawing

This is my code to draw a circle but somehow it has a line draw from the center to the edge of the circle..
I have not add a line to into it only have move to and drawArc.

```
var geometry = Geometry.Instance;
        var path = new UIBezierPath();
        path.MoveTo(new CGPoint((nfloat)centerPiece.Center.X, (nfloat)centerPiece.Center.Y));
        path.AddArc(new CGPoint((nfloat)centerPiece.Center.X, (nfloat)centerPiece.Center.Y), centerPiece.Radius, 0.0f, (float)Math.PI * 2, true);
        context.SetLineWidth(centerPiece.BorderWidth);
        context.SetStrokeColor(GetBorderPaint(centerPiece));

        context.AddPath(path.CGPath);
        context.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.Stroke);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method to create your `UIBezierPath`:

```
(UIBezierPath *)createArcPath
{
   UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake((nfloat)centerPiece.Center.X, (nfloat)centerPiece.Center.X)
                           radius:(nfloat)centerPiece.Radius
                           startAngle:0
                           endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360)
                           clockwise:YES];
   return aPath;
}
```

This could be a useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29617215/3844242) as well!

Comment: Thanks. The line moveTo was the cause.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved the problem. If my answer was helpful can you please upvote it or mark it as an answer? :)