# Assigning reference to Shape in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

Just started with Swift (and OOO in general about a week ago so bear with me).

Following this "tutorial" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwDJspl5sbg), I was able to get the following code which draws a grid of circles.

```
 //get the bounds of the view we're in
    let viewWidth = self.view.bounds.width
    let viewHeight = self.view.bounds.height

    //set parameters for gride of circles
    let margin: CGFloat = 25
    let xMargin = margin
    let yMargin = margin
    let circleBreathingSpace: CGFloat = 5
    let circleLineWidth: CGFloat = 4

    let across: CGFloat = 6
    let gridRowWidth: CGFloat = viewWidth - (2.0 * margin)
    let cellWidth: CGFloat = gridRowWidth / across
    let cellHeight: CGFloat = cellWidth
    let down: CGFloat = (viewHeight - (2 * yMargin)) / cellHeight

    let circleRadius: CGFloat = (cellWidth - (2 * circleBreathingSpace)) / 2


    //draw the grid
    for xx in 0..<Int(across){
        for yy in 0..<Int(down){
            let circleX: CGFloat = xMargin + ((CGFloat(xx) + 0.5) * cellWidth)
            let circleY: CGFloat = yMargin + ((CGFloat(yy) + 0.5) * cellHeight)

            //Draw Circle [ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616992/how-do-i-draw-a-circle-in-ios-swift ]
            let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: circleX,y: circleY),
                                          radius: circleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(0),
                                          endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2),
                                          clockwise: true)


            let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

            //change the fill color
            shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            //you can change the stroke color
            shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            //you can change the line width
            shapeLayer.lineWidth = 6.0

            view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)




        }
    }
```

**Question**
Now what I'm wondering is how I can give a "reference" to each of these individual circles to manipulate their properties later on.

**Context**
I basically want to have a grid of these circles slowly disappear according to an input of time.  So if I have 20 minutes as an input, I'll get 20 circles and each will take 60 seconds to disappear.  That's just context for what I'm doing, not necessarily the question itself (although any direction in that area wouldn't hurt either :) )

**My Thoughts**
My idea was maybe to create an array and add the circle currently being created to this array.  Then I could loop through the array after and slowly decrease the size of each circle making them shrink and disappear one by one.  Even if that is a feasible solution, I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could create an array for those layers:

```
var shapeLayers = [CAShapeLayer]()
```

Then, as you create shape layers, you can `add` them to that array.

---

Alternatively, you might want to use an array of arrays (in effect, a two dimensional array) so that it more accurately mirrors the visual representation. You could do something like above, creating an array and adding shapes to the array for each row, and then create another array to hold those individual arrays for the rows of shape layers. But maybe more elegant, you can use `map` calls to build the array of array of `CAShapeLayer` objects.

The basic idea is that you take a range of integers to build an array. Let's consider a simple example where I want a simple array of 10 `Int` objects, 0, 2, 4, ... 18:

```
let array = (0 ..< 10).map { (i) -> Int in
    return i * 2
}
```

But this works for building an array of `CAShapeLayer` objects, too:

```
let shapeArray = (0 ..< 10).map { (xx) -> CAShapeLayer in
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    // ... configure that shapeLayer here
    return shapeLayer
}
```

So that builds a "row" of `CAShapeLayer` objects, as `xx` progresses from 0 to 10.

You can then nest that inside an `map` for all of the rows, too. So the inner `map` returns an array of `CAShapeLayer` objects, but the outer `map` returns an array of those arrays, and in ending up with a `[[CAShapeLayer]]`:

```
let arrayOfArrays = (0 ..< 20).map { (yy) -> [CAShapeLayer] in
    return (0 ..< 10).map { (xx) -> CAShapeLayer in
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        // ... configure that shapeLayer here
        return shapeLayer
    }
}
```

You can then iterate through those like so:

```
for shapeLayers in arrayOfArrays {
    for shapeLayer in shapeLayers {
        // do something with `shapeLayer`, e.g.

        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

So, going back to your example:

```
let viewWidth = view.bounds.width
let viewHeight = view.bounds.height

//set parameters for gride of circles
let margin: CGFloat = 25
let xMargin = margin
let yMargin = margin
let circleBreathingSpace: CGFloat = 5
let circleLineWidth: CGFloat = 6

let across: CGFloat = 6
let gridRowWidth: CGFloat = viewWidth - (2.0 * margin)
let cellWidth: CGFloat = gridRowWidth / across
let cellHeight: CGFloat = cellWidth
let down: CGFloat = (viewHeight - (2 * yMargin)) / cellHeight

let circleRadius: CGFloat = (cellWidth - (2 * circleBreathingSpace)) / 2

//build the grid
let circles = (0 ..< Int(down)).map { (yy) -> [CAShapeLayer] in
    return (0 ..< Int(across)).map { (xx) -> CAShapeLayer in
        let circleX: CGFloat = xMargin + ((CGFloat(xx) + 0.5) * cellWidth)
        let circleY: CGFloat = yMargin + ((CGFloat(yy) + 0.5) * cellHeight)

        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: circleX, y: circleY),
                                      radius: circleRadius, startAngle: 0,
                                      endAngle: .pi * 2,
                                      clockwise: true)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = circleLineWidth

        return shapeLayer
    }
}

for row in circles {
    for shapeLayer in row {
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

---

By the way, if you want them to disappear over time, you might consider a repeating timer. And I'd animate them going to `clear` color:

```
var row = 0
var col = 0
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { timer in
    let shapeLayer = circles[col][row]

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    animation.fromValue = 1
    animation.toValue = 0
    animation.duration = 2
    shapeLayer.opacity = 0

    shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)

    row += 1
    if row >= circles[0].count {
        row = 0
        col += 1
        if col >= circles.count {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image: fade]

Note, it might be tempting to use the nested `for` loop pattern (like we did when adding the shape layers to the layer hierarchy), creating a separate timer for each circle to be removed, but that introduces two issues:

First, if you have to cancel all of these, you don't really want to have to iterate through arrays of timers in order to cancel them. It's nicer to be able to `invalidate` a single repeating timer. Second, the firing of multiple timers scheduled in the future can be thrown off by "timer coalescing" (where, in an effort to save power, the OS will start firing off distant timers in groups). Yes, you can use GCD timers and turn off timer coalescing, but repeating timer eliminates the issue altogether.

---

I notice that you wanted the circles to shrink, rather than fade, like I did above. So you could do the following:

```
let viewWidth = view.bounds.width
let viewHeight = view.bounds.height

//set parameters for gride of circles
let margin: CGFloat = 25
let xMargin = margin
let yMargin = margin
let circleBreathingSpace: CGFloat = 5
let circleLineWidth: CGFloat = 6

let across: CGFloat = 6
let gridRowWidth: CGFloat = viewWidth - (2.0 * margin)
let cellWidth: CGFloat = gridRowWidth / across
let cellHeight: CGFloat = cellWidth
let down: CGFloat = (viewHeight - (2 * yMargin)) / cellHeight

let circleRadius: CGFloat = (cellWidth - (2 * circleBreathingSpace)) / 2

//build the grid
let circles = (0 ..< Int(down)).map { (yy) -> [CAShapeLayer] in
    (0 ..< Int(across)).map { (xx) -> CAShapeLayer in
        let circleX: CGFloat = xMargin + ((CGFloat(xx) + 0.5) * cellWidth)
        let circleY: CGFloat = yMargin + ((CGFloat(yy) + 0.5) * cellHeight)

        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: .zero,
                                radius: circleRadius, startAngle: 0,
                                endAngle: .pi * 2,
                                clockwise: true)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: circleX, y: circleY)
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = circleLineWidth

        return shapeLayer
    }
}

//add grid to view's layer
for row in circles {
    for shapeLayer in row {
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

Note, I tweaked that so that the path was about `.zero`, but moved the `position` of the layer to where I wanted the circle. That allows me to simply adjust the scale of the `transform` of the layer when I want them to disappear:

```
var row = 0
var col = 0

Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { timer in
    let shapeLayer = circles[col][row]

    let transformAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")

    let transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0, 0, 1)
    transformAnimation.fromValue = shapeLayer.transform
    transformAnimation.toValue = transform
    transformAnimation.duration = 2
    shapeLayer.transform = transform

    shapeLayer.add(transformAnimation, forKey: nil)

    row += 1
    if row >= circles[0].count {
        row = 0
        col += 1
        if col >= circles.count {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image: shrinking]

Answer (score 0):

Drawing and later changing layers is explained in: https://www.raywenderlich.com/90488/calayer-in-ios-with-swift-10-examples
In your case you could put the layers in an array and change them later right as you mentioned in your thoughts.

Alternatively you could try to use CABasicAnimation https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cabasicanimation and have the animated property be the radius.